# Downloaded Vim through Chocolatey: Is the error 'Attempt to use original download file name failed for...' a problem?

Tags: chocolatey

I received the following error when downloading Vim through Chocolatey:

```
Attempt to use original download file name failed for 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\vim\tools\gvim_9.0.1148_x64.zip'.
Copying vim from 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\vim\tools\gvim_9.0.1148_x64.zip'  
Extracting C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\vim\9.0.1148\vimInstall.zip to C:\tools...  
vim may be able to be automatically uninstalled.  
Environment Vars (like PATH) have changed.   
Close/reopen your shell to see the changes (or in powershell/cmd.exe just type `refreshenv`). 
The install of vim was successful. Software installed to 'C:\tools'.
```

Is this a problem? It seems to work fine on first inspection. I'm really not sure if I need to worry about this.

Comment: 1. This has nothing to do with Vim so I removed the tag. 2. This has nothing to do with programming or programming tools so I voted to close. Use Chocolatey's official support channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message isn't a problem. I actually thought it came through as a warning, at most.

It essentially means "chocolatey was expecting a URL, but found a local file."